# How to notify webmaster when a form is sent with an HTML based e-mail

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Basically I have a form on my page and when an user fills it and sends, the code for it to be sent to me is (PHP):

```
$webmater = myemail@mail.com;
$from = $user_name;
$body = "Name: $user_name \n".
        "E-mail: $user_email \n".
        "Subject: $user_subject \n".
        "Message: $user_message \n";
$headers = 'From: '.$from.' <'.$user_email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $user_email;
mail($server, $user_subject, $body, $headers);
```

Is there a way to insert a page inside the $body? Like:

```
$body = "<html>Lalalala.......</html>";
```

I actually tried it, but the page ends up sending me all the code I built. Basically I don't want that 'crappy' info text to be sent to the e-mail. I want it with a certain design. Is it possible?

Comment: First link that popped up when I Googled it: [**Sending Nice HTML Email with PHP**](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/). Did you even try?

Comment: @JosephSilber I did, although I was probably using the wrong keywords for the search. Thanks though for your link, looks like it's exactly what I was looking for ;)

Comment: All I searched for was **[PHP HTML email](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+html+email)**.

Comment: I was typing "embed html in mail", "php form mail html" and stuff >.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the HTML content type to the headers:

```
$body = "<html>Lalalala.......</html>";
$headers = 'From: '.$from.' <'.$user_email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $user_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
mail($server, $user_subject, $body, $headers);
```

Read this nice article: [**Sending Nice HTML Email with PHP**](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/).

Comment: And then where do I insert the html?

Comment: @coldpumpkin - Right there in the body.

Comment: Alright, let me try. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: By the way, I can't use CSS, can I?

Comment: @coldpumpkin - You could use CSS, but there are many things that aren't supported. See here: [email CSS support](https://www.google.com/search?q=email+css+support).

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot Joseph.